# How to get part of string separated by specific character?

Tags: split, tcl

For example I have this file (can be either one):

```
z:/test/output/AX_001_123_890_v01.exr
z:/test/output/AX_001_123_890_v01_preview_lores.exr
```

I used this code to extract the filename :

```
[file rootname [file tail [value root.name]]]
```

output =

```
AX_001_123_890_v01  
AX_001_123_890_v01_preview_lores
```

Next I want to extract just the `AX_001_123` part only (or the first 3 segment from left). What is the simplest way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you have any difficulty using split and/or using join? The documentation is pretty straightforward: [`split`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [`join`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm) and [`lrange`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lrange.htm) (this gets a sublist of elements from a list):

```
set input "AX_001_123_890_v01"
set output [join [lrange [split $input "_"] 0 2] "_"]
# AX_001_123

set input "AX_001_123_890_v01_preview_lores"
set output [join [lrange [split $input "_"] 0 2] "_"]
# AX_001_123
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to consider a regular expression using [`[regsub]`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm) to extract a prefix string:

```
% regsub {^(([^_]+_){0}[^_]+).*$} "AX_001_123_890_v01" {\1}
AX
% regsub {^(([^_]+_){1}[^_]+).*$} "AX_001_123_890_v01" {\1}
AX_001
% regsub {^(([^_]+_){2}[^_]+).*$} "AX_001_123_890_v01" {\1}
AX_001_123
% regsub {^(([^_]+_){3}[^_]+).*$} "AX_001_123_890_v01" {\1}
AX_001_123_890
% regsub {^(([^_]+_){4}[^_]+).*$} "AX_001_123_890_v01" {\1}
AX_001_123_890_v01
```

- The regular expression uses a quantifier `{0}`, `{1}`, ... to match a specific number `n` of sub-expressions `([^_]+_)` against the input string. This number `n` equals `(m-1)`, with `m` being the number of "elements" you want to find.
- A regex-based approach does not require the input string (and its substrings) qualifying as valid Tcl lists.
- You save some command calls.
- Disclaimer: I am not a regex wizard, so the above expression could be improved, maybe, beyond my understanding.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> n = 3
>>> groups = text.split('_')
>>> '_'.join(groups[:n]), '_'.join(groups[n:])
```

This will give you two the two required groups in python.

Comment: Thanks but i'm looking for  TCL syntax :-)